# Level of integration between Microsoft CDN and ScriptManager with EnableCDN

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, microsoft-cdn

Is there any integration going on, or EnableCDN=true just points script src to hardcoded locations on CDN?

> Using ASP.NET Ajax from the CDN
>
> When using ASP.NET 4, you can redirect
>   all requests for ASP.NET framework
>   scripts to the CDN.

Are `<asp:ScriptManager EnableCDN="true" />` and CDN integrated so that I can configure ScriptManager to get the scripts *combined* from the CDN?

Or is combining the ASP.NET Ajax files (`CompositeScript`) incompatible with getting then from the CDN?

**Note:** I'm talking about a possible integration between Microsoft products: Microsoft's Ajax scripts served by Microsoft's CDN with calls handled by Microsoft's ScriptManager control.
I.e. ScriptManager would tell CDN which of their javascript files it wanted *conbined*.

Comment: I know... "just test it yourself!" Thing is I can't, it's holiday (till Thursday) and I don't have Visual Studio at home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not possible - composite script will combine local scripts (i.e. scripts from your file system/web site). If you think about it, your question does not make any sense - purpose of using CDN hosted script (as opposed to hosted by your web site) is that CDN will probably serve the script faster (it may have been already cached) as opposed to download it from your web site. Any combined scripts will always be hosted on your web site (because your combining them - right) - so they cannot be delivered from third party CDN (because they don't host your combined script)!

Said that what you should do is

1. Deliver scripts such as jquery or microsoft ajax via CDN
2. Deliver your scripts via CompositeScript

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it was unnecessarily rude. Combining the files on my side and then getting them from the CDN wouldn't make sense. But my question was the opposite: **Is ScriptManager and Microsoft CDN integrated so that somehow CND could serve combined scripts?**

Comment: @tiagoinu - I am just trying to appeal to your reasoning! If u think about it, script combining (creating content) isn't really a competency of CDN but serving content is. To provide such feature, CDN has to download scripts for ur site(implies a public site) & also track changes to your scripts - is it feasible, yes! is it available - not to my knowledge. Perhaps, as alternate solution, you may consider building a combined/minimized script in a build process and then serving such script from free/commercial CDN (e.g. http://www.coralcdn.org/ is free CDN while Akamai, Amazon are commercial)

Comment: Ok, I was seeing MS CDN as something that could be smart, as in serve their (own) content on different ways (eg composites).   Accepted your answer but still will test tho, can't hurt.